# PHP + PDO Pagination while Searching in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I'm getting a syntax error while trying to do php pagination in a database search.
What am I doing wrong?

**Function:**

```
public function searchItem1($search, $page) {
        $limit = '5';
        $start = ($page * $limit)-5;
        echo $start;
        $where = array();

        $words = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search);

        array_unshift($words, '');
        unset($words[0]);

        $sqlstring = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($words), "itemname LIKE ?"));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE $sqlstring LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
        echo $sql;
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($words AS $index => $word) {
            $stmt->bindValue($index, "%" . $word . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue($index + 2, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**Error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''5' OFFSET 0'
>   at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php:312 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php(312):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\test.php(59):
>   USER->searchItem1('dois', '1') #2 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\aDatabase2\class.user.php on line 312

Comment: Echo both `$sql` and `$sql1` and paste the result in the question.

Comment: try `$limit = 5;` on line 2

Comment: The limit can be 0,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it like this, with help from @Inurosen comment, took the " ' ' " off the $limit (perpage).

Also, added `$stmt->bindValue($index + 1, "%" . $word . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);` so I can search each word in two columns at the same time(in the title and in the description).

Working perfectly (as far as I can tell) like this:

```
public function searchItem1($search, $page) {
    $limit = 5;
    $start = ($page * $limit)-$limit;
    $where = array();

    $words = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $search);

    array_unshift($words, '');
    unset($words[0]);

    $sqlstring = implode(" OR ", array_fill(0, count($words), "itemname LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?"));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE $sqlstring LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    foreach ($words AS $index => $word) {
        $stmt->bindValue($index, "%" . $word . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, "%" . $word . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue($index + 2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue($index + 3, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: `/[\s]+` = `/\s+/`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I never could pass "limit" statements by binding them through PDO. You may pass them by concatening on query like:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM item WHERE itemname LIKE ? OR description LIKE ? LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start";
```

[EDIT]
After doing that, i forgot to say that you have to delete the lines with the "bindings"

```
    $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue($index + 2, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: won't that give me a  "mixed named and positional parameters" fatal error?

Comment: well, after you put these parameters by concatenation, you have to delete the following lines:

        $stmt->bindValue($index + 1, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue($index + 2, $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Comment: I'd still be mixing named and positional parameters in one query